# quotes syntax errors?

Tags: php

i am having trouble doing a quoting of the following code:

```
<?php

...
header("Location:synopsis.php?id=<?php $id=$_GET["id']; echo $id; ?>"" ?>
```

What should be correct syntax for such a code?

Comment: you can't use php tag inside another php tag.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `Location` header takes an absolute URI (even if most browsers will recover from an author using a relative one)

Second, you have to use the same kind of quote to close a string as you do to open one.

Third, you don't need to copy a variable from `$_GET` before you use it

Fourth, you can't embed a PHP block (`<?php … ?>`) inside another one. Concatenate strings using the `.` operator instead.

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://example.com/synopsis.php?id=" . $_GET["id"]);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
header("Location: synopsis.php?id=" . $id);
```

Besides that you have mixed single quotes with double quotes do you have a problem in your code that you're trying to open php `<?php` when it's already opened.

Answer (score 0):

you can't open a php-tag inside of another. try it like this:

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];

header("Location:synopsis.php?id=".$id);

?>
```