# location header syntax error

Tags: php

Firstly, I got a database of which I labelled different id for different content. However, I also made a comment box, of which my comments are all numbered by id=1,2,3... so whenever I submit a comment, it is able to link it back to the correct id I got earlier (not the comment box id), i.e. if I entered in www.example.com/synopsis?id=1, I will go back there. However, I have a delete.php file which is linked to reload.php file, whereby the page is reloaded. From this, it is unable to go back to the synopsis?id=1, instead it's just synopsis?id=

Here is my code for the submit comment button

```
<form action="synopsis.php?id=<?php $id =$_GET["id"]; echo $id; ?>" method="POST">
```

and this works.

Here is the reload.php file, which doesn't work, and I want it to be back to synopsis?id=1 everytime I hit delete

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$refresh = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM dvd where id=$id",$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Location:synopsis.php?id=<?php $id =$_GET["id"]; echo $id; ?>");
?>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Correct string concatenation:

```
header("Location:synopsis.php?id=" . $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already set the $id variable, you don't need to set it again

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$refresh = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM dvd where id=$id",$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Location:synopsis.php?id=". $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [quotes syntax errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963929/quotes-syntax-errors)

> Anyways :

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$refresh = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM dvd where id=$id",$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Location:synopsis.php?id=".$_GET['id']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<?php` is used to switch from HTML to PHP mode, but in this code you're already in PHP mode:

```
header("Location:synopsis.php?id=<?php $id =$_GET["id"]; echo $id; ?>");
```

It's also good practice to escape variables when you build a new query string:

```
header("Location: synopsis.php?" . http_build_query(array(
    'id' => $_GET['id'],
)));
```